# Print array diagonally

Tags: c#, algorithm

I want to print diagonals from the following matrix

```
XVSOKG
WTPLHD
UQMIEB
RNJFCA
```

starting from bottom right corner so output should be A, B, C, D etc..
I wrote down elements and following indices like this
A [3,5], B[2,5], C[3,4], D[1,5], E[2,4], F[3,3] and so on but I cannot find out any pattern from this. How am I suppose to do this?

Comment: `A [3,5], B[2,5], C[3,4], D[1,5], E[2,4], F[3,3` this is not diagonal anything, its just letters in consecutive order plucked from an array, in fact this whole question is completely confusing. before asking a question try getting all your facts right, using the appropriate terminology, and adding the right input and desired outputs in a concise manner

Comment: Why not just order the matrix to be linearly and then use a nested forloop like a normal person?

Comment: There are diagonals, A is first, BC is second, DEF is third etc..
@AustinWBryan because alphabet in the matrix is just an example, could be any other way of order of letters.

Comment: @firebone I get that it's an example, but you can still organize the matrix to be linear. I mean, what's the point in doing it diagonally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern in fact is quite simple, the problem is that you need to be aware of the borders. I made a function that does what you are looking for (if i didn't misunderstand, for the matrix you posted you wanted the alphabet to be printed).
Unfortunaly I don't have any setup to do this in C# so I did it in Java, I hope you can simplify it and port it easily.

I tested with diferent sizes of matrices but... you know. Test it if you can.

With the following matrix:

```
String[][] matrix = new String[][]{
            {"X","V","S","O","K","G"},
            {"W","T","P","L","H","D"},
            {"U","Q","M","I","E","B"},
            {"R","N","J","F","C","A"}
        };
```

the result is:

```
3 - 5 = A
2 - 5 = B
3 - 4 = C
1 - 5 = D
2 - 4 = E
3 - 3 = F
0 - 5 = G
1 - 4 = H
2 - 3 = I
3 - 2 = J
0 - 4 = K
1 - 3 = L
2 - 2 = M
3 - 1 = N
0 - 3 = O
1 - 2 = P
2 - 1 = Q
3 - 0 = R
0 - 2 = S
1 - 1 = T
2 - 0 = U
0 - 1 = V
1 - 0 = W
0 - 0 = X
```

## The code is the following:

(this looks long, but its mostly comments)

```
/**
 * Prints the diagonals of a matrix from bottom right to top left.
 * 
 * @param matrix the matrix to print
 */
public static void printDiagonals(String[][] matrix){
    // extract the width and the height of the matrix
    int width = matrix[0].length;
    int height = matrix.length;

    /**
     * these are the pointers that go through the matrix, we inicialize it
     * in the bottom right corner 
     */
    int xIndex = width - 1;
    int yIndex = height - 1;
    /**
     * these are auxiliar pointers to let me trace in what diagonal is the
     * next, they are optional but help making the code more clear; I 
     * initialize it with the position above the bottom right corner
     */
    int startingX = xIndex;
    int startingY = yIndex - 1;

    //while we have not reach the top left corner
    while (xIndex >= 0 && yIndex >= 0){
        // print the current index and the value, here change it with watever you need
        System.out.println(yIndex + " - " + xIndex + " = " + matrix[yIndex][xIndex]);
        /**
         * as we are moving diagonally to the bottom left we achieve this by
         * decreasing the x index and increasing the Y index
         */
        xIndex--;
        yIndex++;
        //if we hit one of the borders
        if (yIndex == height || xIndex < 0){
            //move the indices to the next diagonal
            yIndex = startingY;
            xIndex = startingX;
            //then we adjust the next diagonal
            if (startingY > 0){
                startingY--;
            } else {
                startingX--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```